# the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process ioexception

Tags: c#, filestream, streamwriter

Not so sure why I have already use `using` and `fs.Close()` and `file.Close()` but I am still getting this error the second time I run these code.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {

        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            // Display header
            string header = string.Format("{0,-40} {1,-12} {2,-15} {3,-8}",
                                          "Product Name", "Unit Price", "Quantity", "Total");
            file.WriteLine(header);

            foreach (var item in shoppingCart2)
            {
                file.WriteLine("{0,-40} {1,-12} {2,-15} {3,-8}", item.ProductName,
                    Utility.FormatAmount(item.UnitPrice), item.QuantityOrder,
                    Utility.FormatAmount(item.TotalAmount));

                table.AddRow(item.ProductName, Utility.FormatAmount(item.UnitPrice),
                    item.QuantityOrder, Utility.FormatAmount(item.TotalAmount));
            }

            table.Options.EnableCount = false;
            table.Write();
            file.Close();
        }
        fs.Close();
    }
```

Comment: The problem is not here ... What do you do with the file later? Are you openning it in another process? (off-topic hint: you don't need Close if you Dispose)

Comment: Try and use Process Explorer to figure out which process is actually locking your file. Is it really your program?

Comment: Do you have the file open in anther editor for debugging?

Comment: Could it be I am using `filePath` which I declared earlier? `var filePath = "c:/file/Receipt.txt";`

Comment: @tymtam. No, I closed all the Receipt.txt from Notepad

Comment: I noticed I do have this after my code `Attachment attachment;
                attachment = new Attachment(filePath);` Indeed, this is the issue. After commenting these, the error no more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize I have attached the file after my original code:

```
 Attachment attachment;
 attachment = new Attachment(filePath);
```

So, my fixes is to dispose it, then the error is gone.

```
attachment.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Probablly your file is still locked. fs.close or using statement do not release file imidiately, it can take some time.

I understand that you want to read this file next time, and thats when you get the error. So before reading file next time you can try:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        read this file from this place
        break;
    }
    catch 
    { 
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

It is not the perfect solution, but you can verify by this what is happening, and get closer to the solution.

fs.close() and file.close() are unnecessary because using statement closes this files for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is somewhere else (you may have the file open in a separate editor).

Nevertheless, I would suggest using [`WriteAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_WriteAllLines_System_String_System_String___) for this scenario. It would minimise the time the file is open.

Please note that with `WriteAllLines` *'if the target file already exists, it is overwritten'*.

```
const string template = "{0,-40} {1,-12} {2,-15} {3,-8}";
var lines = new List<string>();

lines.Add(string.Format(template, "Product Name", "Unit Price", "Quantity", "Total"));
foreach (var item in shoppingCart2)
{
    lines.Add(string.Format(template, item.ProductName,
        Utility.FormatAmount(item.UnitPrice), item.QuantityOrder,
        Utility.FormatAmount(item.TotalAmount)));

    table.AddRow(item.ProductName, Utility.FormatAmount(item.UnitPrice),
        item.QuantityOrder, Utility.FormatAmount(item.TotalAmount));
}

table.Options.EnableCount = false;
table.Write();
File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines);
```